# HTML5 Video Background Fallback

Tags: html, html5-video, fallback

I've tried this code and it doesn't seem to be working I'm trying to create a fallback so if a non html5 browser (ie/safari) loads the website it'll show different content without the video.

```
<?php if (Modernizr.video) {
<video id="video" src="video.ogv" autoplay />
}
else 
{
<img src="text.jpg">
}?>
```

Any feed back would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the issue lies in the confusion of what is done on the server side versus what is done on the client side. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a JavaScript library. Putting it's code into PHP blocks won't do anything for you since PHP is a server-side technology and JavaScript is not.

An alternative would be using PHP to provide JavaScript with the necessary data and then using JavaScript to determine the HTML to display.

```
<script>
if (Modernizr.video) {
    document.write('<video id="video" src="<?php echo 'video.ogv'; ?>" autoplay />');
} else {
    document.write('<img src="<?php echo 'text.jpg'; ?>" />');
}
</script>
```

You would put this code in the HTML where you want the video/image to display. Note that we use PHP to echo out the filenames. This allows you to provide the filenames dynamically. To take advantage of HTML5's features, I'd recommend placing the filenames into HTML5 data-* attributes, and then using JavaScript to handle all occurrences of video simultaneously.

```
<div class="has-video" data-video="<?php echo 'video.ogv'; ?>" data-image="<?php echo 'text.jpg'; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Is they any way I can stead of showing a picture maybe show coding ?<video id="video" src="http://www.html5-fullscreen-video.com/videos/movie_3.ogv" autoplay />
 


 

  <?php if(get_cfm('Full-Screen BG')): ?>
   <?php foreach(get_cfm('Full-Screen BG') as $image): ?>  
    <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $image->image_url; ?>" alt="" /></a>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

Comment: So if video isn't support then show the images created by full-screen bg function?

Comment: Yes, you are able to put whatever HTML that you want there. Make sure that you keep in mind that you can use PHP to create JavaScript code, but not vice versa. PHP is run on the server and JavaScript is run on the client.

Comment: I tried this out and it isn't working is they anything wrong with my coding... <script>
if (Modernizr.video) {
    document.write('<video id="video" src="http://www.html5-fullscreen-video.com/videos/movie_3.ogv" autoplay />');
} else {
    document.write('<?php if(get_cfm('Full-Screen BG')): ?>
   <?php foreach(get_cfm('Full-Screen BG') as $image): ?>  
    <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $image->image_url; ?>" alt="" /></a>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>" />');
}
</script>

Comment: It's possible that the semicolon after your src attribute is causing issues. Other than that, the code looks fine assuming you are inputting it into your HTML at the point of the video, Modernizr is loaded prior to that point in the code, and your PHP is not throwing errors.